# "They're going gorilla watching" - is there a verb at the end of the sentence?

Tags: verbs, gerunds

In this sentence:

> They're going gorilla **watching**.

what's the function of the verb **watching**?

Is it a verb? a noun? ... maybe **gorilla watching** means "mirador de gorilas", in spanish?

In English, I have not seen a verb at the end of a sentece.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> They **are going** gorilla **watching**.

The key verb here is **are**, it forms the [Present Progressive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_continuous_(English)) tense together with the present participle **going**.

The word **watching** it not really a full-fledged verb but a **[gerund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund)**: it functions as a noun. It is used here to describe the activity of "watching gorillas".

We use the **go + ..ing** structure to describe activities in which people are free to move about and which have no fixed beginning or end:

> - "Let's **go skating** today!" (let us go to the skating rink and skate some time there: the proposed activity is *skating*)
> - "No, let's **go watching** gorillas today!" (let us go to the zoo and watch the gorillas there for some time: the proposed activity is *watching*)
> - "Oh, I didn't know you liked **gorilla watching**!" (I didn't know you liked this activity: *gorilla watching*)

The word **gorilla** is used as an adjective to describe the noun word **watching**.

> I like **[trainspotting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railfan#Trainspotting)**. (I like to spot trains)
>   I like **[birdwatching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birdwatching)**!  (I like to watch birds)
>   I like **gorilla watching**. (I like to watch gorillas)

When a noun like "gorilla" is used in the adjective sense, it is called "**[noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)**".

Gorilla watching is not a very popular pastime: if more people start spending their free time watching gorillas, the two words might fuse into "gorillawatching", like "birdwatching".

---

Reference: Michael Swan, Practical English Usage, Unit 228 (on *"go + ..ing"*), Units 293-300 (on *participles and gerunds*).

Answer (score 2):

"They are going gorilla watching". The function of "watching" in the sentence is that it has been used as a gerund (-ing form of the verb that is used as a noun).

We use a gerund after the verb "go" for some specific activities, especially recreational, that are done out of doors, for example, go shopping, fishing, sightseeing, fishing, jogging, skiing, gorilla watching, etc.